# Pass char * to delphi dll function/procedure

Tags: c++, delphi

I have delphi function that take string parameter:

```
function a(param: string): integer;
begin
{do something}
end
```

How do I call that function from c++?  I switched string to pchar or pansichar but that didn't work. C++ typedef is

```
typedef int (*StringFunction) (char *a);
```

I run it like

```
char *b = "abc";
StringFunction sf;
//loading sf
cout << sf(b);
```

Comment: Perhaps the calling convention? Try making both the C++ and the Delphi routine `stdcall` or `cdecl`.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot call that function from C++. The Delphi `string` type is a private Delphi type. For interop you'll want to use a pointer to null-terminated array of characters. In C++ that is `char*`, and in Delphi that is `PAnsiChar`.

What's more, your Delphi function uses the `register` calling convention which is a register based `fastcall` convention. Again, you cannot access that from other languages. You'll need to use one of the standard calling conventions.

The function pointer in your C++ code already passes a `char*`, and uses the `cdecl` calling convention. So you just need to make the Delphi function match:

```
function a(param: PAnsiChar): integer; cdecl;
```

The above declaration is compatible with the C++ code in your question.

---

If you prefer to use `stdcall` then you need to change both Delphi and C++ code.

**Delphi**

```
function a(param: PAnsiChar): integer; stdcall;
```

**C++**

```
typedef int (__stdcall *StringFunction) (char *a);
```

Comment: No, I call delphish function from C, it have to have "cdecl" too?  As Uli answered, I added stdcall, and it works now((

Comment: You can use either `cdecl` or `stdcall`. But the C code in your question uses `cdecl`, so that's why I opted for that in my example. You can use `stdcall` if you wish but you would need to change the C++ code to match.

Comment: @David, perhaps mention wchar and tchar for full story ?

Comment: @Arioch'The Well, I don't believe in `TCHAR` now that Win9x is dead. As for `wchar_t*`, I don't particularly want to get into that here.

Comment: @aptypr Are you looking for more than this? I don't think I've missed anything.

Comment: The second half of my answer, below the horizontal bar, describes exactly what you need to do.